# Joomla's homepage content displayed instead of the article page

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, menu-item

I'm starting a new Joomla 3. x template and I'm finishing the front page index.php, now the problem is when I go to an article the same page is appears (the front-page) how can I create a custom page for articles like articles.php .

index.php : (lot of code that's why I'm using the link)
https://pastebin.com/qSRpc66U

Answer (score 1):

Replace hardcoded HTML content with Joomla code. For example, add this to the main content area to render the component and system messages:

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Use this to render the head:

```
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>
```

Do not include any other tags within the head. Add tags programmatically instead, e.g. see the code you have on how to include stylesheets:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'template.css', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
```

Do the same for your other stylesheets.

Use `$this->setHtml5(true);` to set HTML5 mode.

Set metadata with `$this->setMetadata()`, e.g.:

```
$this->setMetaData('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
```

Note, only set global metadata that you want to appear on all pages. Do not add content-specific meta tags such as title or meta description. These are generated dynamically by components.

Comment: Should I create a article.php or just in index.php ?

Comment: Normally just index.php. If you want to change the way articles look, create template overrides. See documentation https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core and https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides.

Comment: do you have examples for a complete index.php? in my index.php I don't want to show any content